# NestList with a list inside?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, functional-style

I'm new to *Mathematica*, and was looking for more efficient ways to implement the `Do` loop below. `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are all constants, but I'm also using a list in the loop. Is this possible to implement with [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html)? I haven't been able to find any examples with a list being used inside of `NestList`.

```
Do[
X = Tanh[a.input[[i]] + b.X + c];
Y = d.X;
YOut = Append[YOut, Y];
 ,{i, Length[input]}];
```

Thanks!

*

Sorry for the confusion, I tried to simplify my code for the sake of brevity.

```
Do[
X = Tanh[Win.input[[i]] + Wres.X + Wbias]];
Y = WOUT.X;
YOut = Append[YOut, Y];
, {i, Length[input]}
];
```

`Win`, `Wres`, `Wbias`, and `WOUT` are all appropriately sized matrices. This do loop is part of a testing routine for Reservoir Computing, a type of machine learning.

With help from your answer, I'm rewriting the above as:

```
f = WOUT.(Tanh[Wbias + Win.#2 + WRes.#1]) &;
YOut = FoldList[f, X, input];
```

Will try it out now. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT** - If anyone is looking for a reservoir computing implementation in Mathematica, I've added mine to Github - https://github.com/huvers/reservoir_computing

Comment: Asking a question you should provide always a minimal example of intended input. It saves time and effort of all `mathematica.se` users.

Comment: Nothing against `NestList` or `FoldList`, but a simple `Table` could do this too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking into account clarification after editting the question I guess the most direct solution you are looking for is `Fold` (or `FoldList`) rather than `Nest` (or `NestList`) even though you might succeed with the latter. Regardless of objects `a, b, c, d, X, Y` etc. or `Win, Wbias, WOUT, WRes` being scalars or matrices we can proceed defining an appropriate function for the `Fold` construct.
At first let's define an example of matrix objects:

```
{a, b, c, d} = 
{{{1, 2}, {-1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{-2, 1}, {1, -1}}};
id = IdentityMatrix[2];
input = {0 id, 1 id, 2 id};
```

Next we can define for the following pure function:

```
 f = d.Tanh[ a.#2 + b.#1 + c]&;
```

then it yields `YOut`:

```
FoldList[ f, {{x11, x12}, {x21, x22}}, input]
```

while this yields the last entry of `YOut`:

```
Fold[f, {{x11, x12}, {x21, x22}}, input]
```

For example choosing

```
X = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
```

we have

```
Fold[ f, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, input]
```

> ```
> {{-2 Tanh[2 + Tanh[Tanh[1]] - 2 Tanh[1 + Tanh[1]]] 
>   - Tanh[1 - Tanh[Tanh[1]] + Tanh[1 + Tanh[1]]], 
>   -2 Tanh[ 5 - 2 Tanh[3 - 2 Tanh[1]] + Tanh[1 - Tanh[1]]] 
>   + Tanh[2 - Tanh[3 - 2 Tanh[1]] + Tanh[1 - Tanh[1]]]}, 
>  { Tanh[2 + Tanh[Tanh[1]] - 2 Tanh[1 + Tanh[1]]] 
>   + Tanh[1 - Tanh[Tanh[1]] + Tanh[1 + Tanh[1]]], 
>    Tanh[5 - 2 Tanh[3 - 2 Tanh[1]] + Tanh[1 - Tanh[1]]] 
>   - Tanh[2 - Tanh[3 - 2 Tanh[1]] + Tanh[1 - Tanh[1]]]}}
> ```

Let's choose another example of scalar objects:

```
Clear[f, X, a, b, c, d, id, input]

input = {0, 1, 2};
{a, b, c, d} = {1, 2, 3, 4};
f = d Tanh[a #2 + b #1 + c] &;
```

then we have e.g.

```
Fold[ f, 0, input]
```

> ```
> 4 Tanh[ 5 + 8 Tanh[ 4 + 8 Tanh[3]]]
> ```