# How can I use NestWhileList instead of While in this case?

Tags: programming, functional-style

OK, the problem occurred when I challenged with Project Euler No. 10

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17. Find the sum of
>   all the primes below two million.

My code is:

```
ClearAll[primelist, i]
primelist = {}; i = 1
While[Prime[i] < 2*10^6, AppendTo[primelist, Prime[i]];i++]
Plus @@ primelist
```

And I get the answer correct.
I think using `While` is not a good habit in functional programming, but I can not modify my code to `NestWhileList`(or others FP-like functions).
One of the proper manner is:

```
Plus @@ (Prime /@ NestWhileList[# + 1 &, 1, (Prime[# + 1] < 2*10^6 &)])
```

But I think it is not efficient, because when evaluating the `NestWhileList`,
`Prime[1],Prime[2],Prime[3],...` ran the first time(in order to compare with 2*10^6), and then when mapping Prime to the list which was the result of `NestWhileList`, the same thing went once again!
MMA evaluate `Prime[1],Prime[2],Prime[3],...` one more time.

1. Is there any method (or SOP) that can always change `While` to `NestWhile` or `NestWhileList`?
2. And I found that the second code above run faster much more than code 1, unbelievable.

Answer (score 7):

When using advanced functionality to deal with primes it is highly recommended not using any of `NestList` or `FoldList` or whatever similar.
`PrimePi` is especially designed to find how many primes are below of a given number, then `Prime`  roughly inverse of `PrimePi` is `Listable`, therefore I'd suggest this approach yielding the result almost immediately:

```
Total @ Prime @ Range @ PrimePi @ 2000000
```

> ```
> 142913828922
> ```

See closely related [Generate PrimePower counting function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37397/generate-primepower-counting-function/37400#37400).
If you are to examine something related to  nesting  see e.g. this [NestList with a list inside?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31417/nestlist-with-a-list-inside/31418#31418).

Comment: +1 - Probably the fastest solution available

Comment: @eldo Thanks, when I started to play with _Mathematica_ I used to test something like `Select[ range, PrimeQ]` just to be convinced that there are better ways, however sometimes one can find another interesting solutions, see e.g. [this approach](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37397/generate-primepower-counting-function/39183#39183)

Answer (score 4):

I like to use `Sum` for such things, when possible, as it conserves memory and is usually reasonably fast:

```
Sum[Prime @ i, {i, PrimePi[2*^6]}]
```

> ```
> 142913828922
> ```

Performance (still in v7, for now...) compared to Artes's fully vectorized code, with a larger search space:

```
Sum[Prime @ i, {i, PrimePi[2*^7]}] // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {1.857, 12272577818052}
> 15904176
> ```

```
(* in a fresh kernel *)
Total @ Prime @ Range @ PrimePi[2*^7] // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {1.716, 12272577818052}
> 138293008
> ```

So `Sum` is only slightly slower and uses a fraction of the memory that `Total` does.

---

The performance comparison performed in 10.0.2 under Windows:

```
Sum[Prime @ i, {i, PrimePi[2*^7]}] // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {2.308815, 12272577818052}
>
> 41744320
> ```

```
(* in a fresh kernel *)
Total @ Prime @ Range @ PrimePi[2*^7] // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {2.199614, 12272577818052}
>
> 157160592
> ```

Both methods are slower now and use more memory, but `Sum` remains a good option.

Comment: `i = 0; NestWhile[(++i; # + Prime[i]) &, 0, 
  Prime[i + 1] < 2000000 &] // AbsoluteTiming`
I just figure out this code! It seems elegant. And it is much more fast than Build-in functions!

Comment: The algorithm is `while(Prime[i]<2*10^6){sum=sum+Prime[i];
i++;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
First @ NestWhile[
    With[{p = Prime[#[[3]]]}, 
        {#[[1]] + #[[2]], p, #[[3]] + 1}
    ] &,
    {0, 2, 2}, #[[2]] <= 2 10^6 &
]
```

EDIT: this is a faster version:

```
Total[
   NestWhileList[
       {Prime@#[[2]], #[[2]] + 1} &,
       {0, 1},
       #[[1]] <= 2 10^6 &][[;;-2, 1]]
]
```

Comment: I have found a better(not sure) solution based on your second solution. `NestWhile[{#[[1]] + Prime[#[[2]]], #[[2]] + 1} &, {0, 1}, 
  Prime[#[[2]]] < 2000000 &]  // Timing`

Comment: The first entry of the list is recorded as a sum, the second the counter(is going to be the argument of `Prime`)

Comment: @Eric, my second solution runs a bit faster (in my computer) than your proposal.