# How to sum over primes

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

Apologies in advance for the simplicity of the question, but I can't fathom how to write the following as a sum in *Mathemaitca*:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{p}^{a}\sum_{n}^{b}\text{expression}
\end{align}

where $p$ runs through the primes.

I would like to plot

\begin{align}
&\sum_{p}^{a}\sum_{n}^{b}(1/n)p^{-ns}
\end{align}

in $s$ for some $a,b$.

Comment: @Kuba thankyou very much - I think I haven't quite woken up yet! ;)

Comment: @kuba - should I delete?

Comment: I don't think so. Not bad question. I felt like it is a  dupe but I've faile to find one. Let me post an answer.

Comment: related: [52371](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52371/5478)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
 mySum[s_, a_, b_]:= Sum[  1./n p^(-n s), 
                           {n, b},  
                           {p, Prime @ Range @ PrimePi @ a}]
```

Edit: skipper inner `Sum`, thanks to kguler's comment.

Comment: Simpler: `Sum[1/n p^(-n s), {n, b}, {p, Prime@Range@PrimePi@a}]` (+1)